# Subtract two textsfields that have datepicker

Tags: objective-c, datepicker, nsdate, nscalendar, subtraction

I would like to know how to subtract two textsfields that have datepicker. And display the result into a label. 
Ex.: (25.05.2013) – (17.05.2013) = 1 **week** and 1 **day**

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *then = self.datepicker.date;
NSTimeInterval howLong = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:then];

NSUInteger w, d;
w = (howLong / 604800);
d =


NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" x weeks, y days", w, d];
label1.text = str;
```

Comment: Start calculating from the biggest unit you want to display, e.g. Year, then continue with the next unit, e.g. Month and calculate the remaining.

Comment: Hint: Convert both dates into total number of seconds from 1970.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert `NSString` into `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`.

Then find the interval between both the date, which will give you seconds, then you can convert it into minutes, dates as per your need.

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSDate *date1=[df dateFromString:@"25.05.2013"];
NSDate *date2=[df dateFromString:@"17.05.2013"];

NSInteger interval = (int)[date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2];
```

**Code is not compiled - checked.*

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `NSDateComponents` :

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [form setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

    NSDate *dateA = [form dateFromString:@"17.05.2013"];
    NSDate *dateB = [form dateFromString:@"25.05.2013"];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:dateA
                                                 toDate:dateB
                                                options:0];
    strDiffyear = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", components.year];
    strDiffmonth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",components.month];
    strDiffDays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",components.day];
lblDifference.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ years %@ months %@ days",strDiffyear,strDiffmonth,strDiffDays];
```

You can have many components for date difference divisions.

If any query in answer, Free to ask (: